# When to use @Put Method or straight away using query in Spring Java Data JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

When update an existing field in the table, what is the best practice to consider? Like I do write a lot of `PUT` method which overwrite the existing data when update ( I consider with large objects using a lot of logic and also calculation, it'd be better).
But what about sometimes I just need to update one field? I saw a pattern of using same or similar put method when people update data, in those function, they will check to delete the old one and put the new data into table.
Should it be better if we using an update set JPA query to change exactly what we need?

Like there's an existing function when user create or update the record they have, should I create then add one update set query inside that function so it would update or create into those new set table I create?

Thanks for reading this load of text, I hope to have a clear point of view to become a better programmer.

I did try to google to understand the definition but not so clear. I hope I can get a clearer point of view here.

Comment: If you use hibernate the @DynamicUpdate annotation might be of interest (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-dynamicupdate). I wouldn't say manual implementation of dirty-checks to only update dirty fields is common practice. Not sure if this answers your question, whatever it is, so I just post this as a comment.